# Uploading formData from React Native to Node.js (multer) with axios - Getting AxiosError: Network Error

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, multer, form-data

Im trying to upload an image as FormData for my backend. that is working well without the frontend request (using postman form data setting a key "name" with value "perfil", an a key "file" with the image file). But when i do the request from frontend i get an "axios error: network error".
All the other normal requests (with data that is not form data) are working.

Here is my code of backend:

**Multer.js**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).single("file");
module.exports = upload;
```

**userController.js**

```
exports.addPicture = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const { name } = req.body;
  const file = req.file;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id, "-password");
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "User not found" });
    }
    const oldPicture = await Picture.findOne({ name: "profile" });
    if (oldPicture) {
      if (fs.existsSync(oldPicture.src)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(oldPicture.src);
        oldPicture.remove();
      }
    }
    const picture = new Picture({ name, src: file.path });
    await picture.save();
    user.picture = picture;
    await user.save();
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ picture, msg: "Image updated!" });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      msg: "An error occurs",
    });
  }
  data.append("picture", {
    uri: image,
    name: "perfil.jpg",
    type: "image/jpeg",
  });
};
```

**Picture.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PictureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  src: { type: String, required: true },
});
const Picture = mongoose.model("Picture", PictureSchema);
module.exports = { Picture, PictureSchema };
```

**PictureRoutes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const upload = require("../config/multer");
const pictureController = require("../controllers/pictureController");
const checkToken = require("../middleware/auth");

router.post("/picture", upload, checkToken, pictureController.addNew);
router.delete("/picture/:id", checkToken, pictureController.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my code of frontend:

**ProfileImage.js**

```
import useApi from "../hooks/useApi";
import usersApi from "../api/user";
const ProfileImage = ({}) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const requestMediaPermissions = useMedia((image) => setImage(image));
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [addPictureApi, isLoading, error] = useApi(usersApi.addPicture);

  const handleUpdatePicture = () => {
    if (image == null) return;
    console.log(image);
    //const newImageUri = "file:///" + image.uri.split("file:/").join("");

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", {
      uri: image.uri,
      name: "profile",
      type: image.type,
    });
    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = handleUpdatePicture();

    data &&
      addPictureApi(user.id, data)
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [image]);
```

The image object of state is like this:  {"assetId": null, "base64": null, "cancelled": false, "exif": null, "height": 1080, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImagePicker/86431757-9747-4bd6-b192-b5541f98b9fb.jpeg", "width": 1080}

Please even if the error is not my form data, tell me if im passing the values correctly in append as im not sure if that is right based on my backend logic.

I already tried to apply these headers to my request, but didnt change nothing:

```
headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
```

Already tried to change the uri as another suggestion that i have seen here in stackoverflow but didnt work:

```
const newImageUri =  "file:///" + imageUri.split("file:/").join("");
```

Comment: Nvm, i fixed it changing the form data to  data.append("name", "perfil");
    data.append("file", {
      uri: image,
      name: "photo.jpg",
      type: "image/jpeg",
    });